# What to replace $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] in php 7?

Tags: php, php-7

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is removed in PHP 7.0. In my application, I also have the following line. What is the alternative I can use for this ?

```
if (isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) && 
                                  mb_strlen($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']))
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that code? As it does not do anything besides checking for the existance of that variable, you could simply remove it - unless there's more code following this

Answer (score 11):

According to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php):

> In general, php://input should be used instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

To get the Raw Post Data:

```
<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```

Comment: "In general" is the critical failing here. php://input does not work for "multipart/form-data"  - which is the only encoding type for which I really need raw data.